# Kernel pca and kernel svm

Tags: machine-learning, pca, svm, kernel-trick

PCA is a way to reduces dimension and complexities, but is it ok to use kernel PCA with radial basis function and then use kernel SVM using the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, why not. It's not different from using an ML pipeline with steps `[PCA, SVM]` cascaded. The kernel trick only adds some nonlinearity to these steps/algorithms.